# Right function vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to take everything to the right of the symbol in the string 
I used

```
Right(enclosedValue, InStr(enclosedValue, "*") - 0)
```

where enclosed value  is `29,6 *60`, so I need it to return `*60`, but now it returns

```
,6 *60
```

Sorry if this question has been asked already,
I have just started using vba and I'm a bit confused

Comment: What do you expect `- 0` to do?

Comment: Originaly i did it to include the symbol `*`, as i thought that `- 1` would give me only `60`, I might have been completely wrong though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with `Mid` instead:

```
Mid(enclosedValue, InStr(1, enclosedValue, "*"))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you must use `Right`:

```
Right(enclosedValue, Len(enclosedValue) - InStr(enclosedValue, "*"))
```

Though really, [`Mid` is the way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30838738/119775) to keep the code short and readable.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest route to this is using `Right` as a string function `Right$`. See [here](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt3.html)

The biggest gain though is made by using the string function (ie `Mid$` is far superior to `Mid`)

In descending order:

1. `Right$(StrIn, Len(StrIn) - InStr(1, StrIn, "*") + 1)`
2. `Mid$(StrIn, InStr(1, StrIn, "*"))`
3. `Mid(StrIn, InStr(1, StrIn, "*"))`